# Flag choices - mark which flags have sub-categories

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-dialog

I don't flag questions that often, and when I do it's hard to remember which "root" flag has the sub-categories for things like the wrong stack site or needs more detail.

It would help to have something like "[choose]" or (shows list) "[expand]" next to the flags that lead to secondary choices, for example  **Needs Improvement [choose]** or **Needs Improvement [*show choices*]**

If nothing else I can click it to see the choices and cancel if I picked the wrong flag.  Right now if I click the wrong flag, it takes effect and I can't cancel.

Comment: "If nothing else I can click it to see the choices and cancel if I picked the wrong flag. Right now if I click the wrong flag, it takes effect and I can't cancel." - flags aren't auto-submitted when you click on them. Categories, on the other hand, auto-expand, so this isn't an argument. I fully agree it's unclear when there's a submenu and that it needs to be addressed, but submenus do not act like normal flags when clicked

Comment: Stack Exchange used to indicate which items would open a new panel of the popup with an ellipse: "…". Unfortunately, those were actually *removed* in the most recent major redesign and SE has been either unresponsive or refused when the specific issue has been brought up (multiple times). In other words, yes, there should be some indication. Not having such an indication is just *bad UI design* and results in both poor UX and people not using the site as intended. Unfortunately, all such requests, even though the minimum needed is just *trivial text changes*, have not been acted upon.

Comment: Personally, I like those menus with the triangle icon where you click the triangle and it spins around from pointing right to pointing down, and then inserts additional options in a nested list.